# PCIe card dimension half-length 106.68 mm × 175.26 mm specification deviation

Tags: pcie, electro-mechanical

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) and other sites, the dimensions of the half-length    PCIe card are 106.68 mm × 175.26 mm.

But as per the specification:

[image]

Kindly clarify how the length of 175.26 mm has been arrived at for half-length PCIe cards.

Comment: possibly from the *ATX case soecifications

Comment: This might get a better answer in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/  or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2):

The PCIe electromechanical spec says for the half length form factor if the consumption of the power more than the rated power 10W, then the length must have greater than the Half length form factor. Nowadays most of the GPU, CPU, FPGA card built in Half, full length PCIe form factor and these are all power hungry devices hence most of the time power will be exceeding the rated power 10W, this might be the reason for mentioning in Wikipedia also.

Please find the attached snap shot of the PCI electromechanical specification.
Hope it helps.[image]